# list all files with the same name in order of when they were modified

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, shell, last-modified, date-modified

I have a directory, let's call it `htdocs/live/`. Many different directories are underneath this directory, each with a file `commonFunctions.js` living in the `js` directory.

For example, here is the structure of a few of the directories containing `commonFunctions.js`:

```
htdocs/live/abc123/js/commonFunctions.js
htdocs/live/program1/js/commonFunctions.js
htdocs/live/program2/js/commonFunctions.js
htdocs/live/bunnies/js/commonFunctions.js
htdocs/live/emerald/js/commonFunctions.js
```

How can I write a command to list each of these files ordering them by the last time they were modified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you thinking of something like `ls -alt htdocs/live/*/js/commonFunctions.js` ?

Comment: I did not know you could use the `*` in `ls` like that. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Incidentally, the `*` is a function of the shell, not `ls`. You can use this with any shell command :)